# Axis2 How to create a service instance for other services

Tags: service, eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

My service will load a lot of data (from txt files) to memory every request.
But,I want to keep the data in memory.
Because it is read from same txt files.

```
public class pirTMain {
  public String[] RUN_pirT(...){
  ...
  //this object will read txt files to initialize
  ELC elc = new ELC(elcFolder.getPath()); 

  //use elc to initialize a graph
  pirT.initGraph(userID, nodeFile.getPath(), userScore, elc, true, begin, target); 

  //Use graph to search paths
  itinerary = pirT.search(userID, TopK, begin, beginWithTime, target, targetWithTime); 
  ...
```

I had read Axis2 document.
It says I can change service scope to "application".
But I still don't know how to do it, because I use eclipse plugin to generate a web service *.arr.
Can anyone suggest me how to separate elc object to another service?
Then, my pirTMain class can use it.

pirTMain  is 'request'.

elc is 'application'.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to achieve this, the simplest one that comes in my mind is to create a static reference to the read lines so that it's shared among all threads in the same virtual machine:

```
@WebService
public MyServiceClass {
    private static String[] readLines = null;

    private static synchronized getLines(){
         if (readLines == null)
             readLines = ....;

         return readLines;
    }

    public int getNumberOfLines(){
         return MyServiceClass.getLines().length;
    }

    public String getLine(int position){
         return MyServiceClass.getLines()[position];
    }
    ...

}
```

Probably not the "cleanest" way, but it works and it's easy to do. You could also wrap the login in a more standard "singleton pattern" if you prefer. keep in mind that getLines should be synchronized to be thread safe but if you experience bottlenecks remove the synchronized keyword, you could get useless reads on first calls but it would be faster.

Comment: Can this way keep data in the memory when I read files once?I have little confused how to use this class for another services when front-end request my service.If I read the files every time, server memory will not enough to use.

Comment: readLines is static so it's binded only 1 time in memory. If you have multiple services just create another class with this methods and use that in all your services.